# Ambigious PHP Web Service error message

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

did anyone ever encounter the following error message

> Extra content at the end of the document

when trying to consume a PHP web service from a client
that runs on php 5.3?

I guess soembody did. ^^

Anyways, I don't seem to find an error in the server code which
works for several clients of mine for quite some time now.
Is this possibly a php problem in the recent version?

My client code looks like this:

```
try
{
  $client = new SoapClient("http://someserver/server.php?wsdl", array('trace' => 1, 'feature' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
}   
catch(Exception $e)
{$this->handleException($e);}
```

Any thoughts on this would be highly appreciated.

TIA

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the XML is not well formatted. Is the WSDL generated or created manually?

Comment: created manually, but works at several other installations serving clients from PHP, Java and .NET.

Comment: This is a wild guess since I haven't check out the modified files in v.5.3 but, if they use a new Dom-lib, that could be a PHP issue in our case.

Also searched a bit and found the following two issues:
- By checking the bugs on the PHP site, there was someone with the same error, and then it was about UTF-8 encoding problem. Old thou..
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32712&edit=1

- A other fellow found out that cause of out-of memory, the parsing of XML was not made and gave this error.

Also remember that it does not always be at the end the error occur, moste likely it is in the middle.